# Testing primary_email_confirmed flag during PayPal seller onboarding in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently working on integrating seller onboarding prior to payment processing with PayPal. One of the prerequisites for successful onboarding is that the `primary_email_confirmed` flag must be set to true. However, I've encountered an issue while attempting to test this in the sandbox environment: the test accounts that I create come pre-verified, which means the `primary_email_confirmed` flag is already set to true by default. Hence, I cannot test scenarios for onboarding sellers without existing PayPal account.

Is there a method or workaround to test scenarios in the sandbox environment where primary_email_confirmed is initially false, and then observe it changing to true after the email confirmation process? I'm looking for a way to accurately simulate the email verification step that a real user would experience during onboarding.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant links

- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bizsignup/
- https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts ->  Link other sandbox accounts to this developer account
- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
- https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/notifications